# Appends or Prepends? Depends

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string, classification, brain-flak

> [Brain-flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) turns one year old tomorrow! In honor of it's birthday, we're having a PPCG style birthday party, where several users post brain-flak related questions! [Help us celebrate!](https://hackmd.io/KwRgnARiAcCGAsBaaEBMAGR8DG8Cmis0AZsVhPLOtsWAOzQAmIQA?view) :)

---

Brain-flak is an esoteric language I wrote where all of the commands are brackets and all of the brackets must be fully matched. To borrow [my own definition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77138/31716):

- For the purpose of this challenge, a "bracket" is any of these characters: `()[]{}<>`.
- A pair of brackets is considered "matched" if the opening and closing brackets are in the right order and have no characters inside of them, such as

  ```
  ()
  []{}
  ```

  Or if every subelement inside of it is also matched.

  ```
  [()()()()]
  {<[]>}
  (()())
  ```

  Subelements can also be nested several layers deep.

  ```
  [(){<><>[()]}<>()]
  <[{((()))}]>
  ```
- A string is considered "Fully matched" if and only if:

  1. Every single character is a bracket,
  2. Each pair of brackets has the correct opening and closing bracket and in the right order

In celebration of brain-flak's first birthday, today's challenge is about taking an unbalanced set of brackets, and determining what types of operations are needed to make it valid brain-flak.

- For example, `((` is not valid brain-flak code, but if we append `))` to it, it becomes `(())`, which is fully balanced, and therefore valid brain-flak. That makes this input *appendable*.
- Similarly, `>}` is not valid, but we can prepend `{<` to it to make `{<>}`, which is valid. That makes this input *prependable*.
- Some inputs are slightly more complicated. For example, `)][({` cannot be made valid purely by appending or prepending. But it *can* be made valid by prepending `[(` and appending `})]`. Therefore, this input is both *prependable* and *appendable*.
- Lastly, some inputs can never be made valid brain-flak code by any combination of appending or prepending. For example, `(>` can never be made valid. (Prepending `<` creates `<(>`, and appending `)` creates `(>)`, neither of which are valid) Therefore, this input is neither appendable or prependable.

For today's challenge, you must write a program or function that takes a string of brackets and determines if the string is

```
appendable
prependable
both
neither
```

You may pick what values you use to represent for each case. For example, outputting `1, 2, 3, 4`, or `'a', 'p', 'b', 'n'`, or `1, 'foo', 3.1415, -17`, or whatever is fine. As long as each output is *distinct* and *consistent*, that's fine. You *must* however, clearly specify which output corresponds to which case.

You may return this value in whichever format is most convenient (for example, returning from a function, printing to STDOUT, modifying arguments, writing to a file, etc.).

You can assume that the input will never be valid brain-flak or empty.

## Examples

The following inputs are all *prependable*:

```
))
(((()()())))}
)>}]
()[]{}<>)
```

These are all *appendable*:

```
(({}{})
((((
([]()())(
{<<{
```

These are all *both*:

```
))((
>()[(()){
>{
```

And these are all *neither*:

```
)(}
{(((()()()))>
[}
((((((((((>
((((((((((<>()]
```

As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

---

This challenge is particularly difficult in brain-flak, so maximum [brownie points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownie_points) to any and every answer written in brain-flak. :)

Comment: `maximum brownie points` I think that offering maximum brownie points and cookies instead would encourage Brain-Flaking this challenge more than just brownie points, since I don't think it's trivial at all in *any* language, let alone Brain-Flak. :P

Comment: FYI: All the both tests end with open brackets, all the neither tests end with close brackets.

Comment: I would argue that 'both' is the wrong term. A string like `][` is __not__ appendable, as nothing you can append can make it valid. Similarly, it's not prependable. It's... 'insertable'! You can insert it into a string to make the whole valid Brainflak.

Comment: Are already balanced strings both or neither?

Comment: @wheatwizard Balanced strings won't be given as input. `You can assume that the input will never be valid brain-flak or empty. `

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33 32 37 35</s> 34 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*bug found, horrible fix +5 bytes, better fix - 2 bytes, using a trick of Adnan's I saw [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117996/find-the-first-bracket-match#comment289022_118011) for -1 more.*

```
“({[<“)}]>”Z;@WœṣF¥/µÐLO‘&2µIṀ>0ȯQ
```

Return values:

```
prepends [2]
 appends [0]
    both [2,0]
 neither 1
```

(Invalid input returns spurious results, although valid Brain-flack, returns `[]`.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY5GdbQNkNKsjbV71DA3ytoh/OjkhzsXux1aqn9o6@EJPv6PGmaoGR3a6vlwZ4OdwYn1gf@BynRTTyx/1LjjxPrD7VwPd2853P6oaU3k//@6ugoFRakFqXkpxVyamlwaQKAJgkBQy6VpVxvLpaEZHVtda2OnyQVUm1gAUaqhUV1bXQtRz6URHQvWosFVbWNTDVKWlF@SATQOKGcH1A40UrOay65aA2xEXmpmSUZqEZemRi1XNZJ9dlzRtWDzIMAOiW0DNAXokNhoTa5Ym9hqDQA)** - a test suite (prints mushed representations, so `20` for `[2,0]`, and ignores lines containing any `-`).

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> 41 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
+`\(\)|\[]|{}|<>

[]})>]+
1
\W+
0
...+
01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#TYxBCgMxCEX3/x4FJRA6@@C2R@jCCHMP49nT35nNfBFFH@8ln3O3c8rUNT1W1hoGeJRaNByY34Y3eu8cx96qEEb/xRTUKiDqkTVMwW9W1k1BPC5QkGMkwE1gpGnQhPEk4QpNYnSx86E3eF2iO/bYBy3xAw)

- Prependable is `1`
- Appendable is `0`
- Both is `10`
- None is `01`

#### Edits

- Gained 1 byte to fix bug noticed by @Neil

Comment: `[]})>]` saves a byte.

Comment: @MartinEnder Ah, it's because character sets can't be empty, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for all non-appendable inputs, for example `(][)`. I think it can be fixed at a cost of one byte by changing `101` to `...+`.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for noticing the bug, I wonder if there are such cases with `Both` as well

Comment: No, I think `10` is the only valid combination for `Both`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 337 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
:g
set "t=%s:<>=%
set "t=%t:()=%
set "t=%t:[]=%
set "t=%t:{}=%
if not "%t%"=="%s%" set "s=%t%"&goto g
set "s=%s:<=[%
set s=%s:>=]%
set s=%s:(=[%
set s=%s:)=]%
set s=%s:{=[%
set s=%s:}=]%
:l
if %s:~,2%==]] set s=%s:~1%&goto l
:r
if %s:~-2%==[[ set s=%s:~,-1%&goto l
if not _%s:~2%==_ set s=[]
echo %s%
```

Outputs `]` for prepend, `[` for append, `][` for both, `[]` for neither.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>115</s> 108 bytes

EDIT:

- -7 bytes: Use more guards.

```hs
(""#)
s#""=[s>"",1>0]
s#(c:d)|Just a<-lookup c$zip"([{<"")]}>"=(a:s)#d|(a:b)<-s=[1|a==c]>>b#d|0<1=take 1$s#d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#TUxBjoMwDLz7FchwsKUtKtcq8QP2C1EOKaVa1BZQA1ppQ97OuvTS8cEz4xk/Qj/Yfpi7Z2jnahnu/dDF@hEmij/jb33lene2qyXEkiGWiNZFQfxq5OhVU3u68Pq9xLkI5nAfx9syFW31109ILhlE9lnQUjhFLi@r7jObQ7SuWYO1rRc5q300jZ3DrSuaKpaXbWMGUvBrFBlYsgdi51M28jqmnPI7BOT8niNIxiRQQiCa1T4nEHUoQ/r4J@DyXn1DPrjRood/)

Use like `(""#) "))"`. Results are given as:

```hs
[False,True]: needs nothing
[False]: prependable
[True,True]: appendable
[True]: both
[]: neither
```

## How it works

- The output encoding is chosen such that a need to prepend is signaled by dropping the second element of the result for the remainder, if any, while a complete mismatch is signaled by dropping all of them.
- `s#d` parses a remaining string `d`, given a string/stack `s` of expected closing brackets.

  - The `s#""` line checks if all closing brackets have been found by the end of the string, otherwise appending is needed.
  - The first branch of `s#(c:d)` checks if the next character `c` is an opening bracket, and if so leaves the corresponding closing bracket on the stack for the recursion.
  - Otherwise, if the stack contains closing brackets, the second branch checks if the top one matches the next character, and if not, returns an empty list instead of recursing.
  - Lastly, in the last branch the stack is empty, and we have an unmatched closing bracket that may be fixed by prepending, before recursing.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 137 Bytes

```
for($c=1;$c;)$a=preg_replace("#<>|\(\)|\[\]|\{\}#","",$a=&$argn,-1,$c);echo($a=preg_replace(["#[]})>]+#","#[[{(<]+#"],[1,2],$a))<13?$a:0;
```

1 =>appendable,

2 =>prependable,

12=>both,

0 =>neither

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd0cd30cf376d398620fc72d3f4259e2a15db5df)

Comment: "As long as each output is distinct and **consistent,** that's fine". This doesn't appear to have a consistent value for neither.

Comment: @Cyoce It is now Fixed

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 44 bytes

```
=Ue"%(%)|%[]|\{}|<>" ®c -1&2|1})f31 |UfD |Ug
```

Outputs `1` for prependable, `3` for appendable, `13` for both, and `31` for neither.

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=PVVlIiUoJSl8JVtdfFx7fXw8PiIgrmMgLTEmMnwxfSlmMzEgfFVmRCB8VWc=&input=IigoKCgoKCgoKCg8PigpXSI=) or [Verify all test cases at once.](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=PVVlIiUoJSl8JVtdfFx7fXw8PiIgrmMgLTEmMnwxfSlmMzEgfFVmRCB8VWc=&input=WwogICIpKSIKICAiKCgoKCkoKSgpKSkpfSIKICAiKT59IgogICIoKVtde308PikiCgogICIoKHt9e30pIgogICIoKCgoIgogICIoW10oKSgpKSgiCiAgIns8PHsiCgogICIpKSgoIgogICI+KClbKCgpKXsiCiAgIj5deyIKCiAgIikofSIKICAieygoKCgpKCkoKSkpPiIKICAiW30iCiAgIigoKCgoKCgoKCg+IgogICIoKCgoKCgoKCgoPD4oKV0iCl0gLW0=)

#### How it works

```
 =Ue"%(%)|%[]|\{}|<>" ®   c -1&2|1})f31 |UfD |Ug
U=Ue"%(%)|%[]|\{}|<>" mZ{Zc -1&2|1})f31 |UfD |Ug

                    // "(((()()())))}"  "([({}{})"    ">()[(()){"  "((((<>()]"
Ue"%(%)|%[]|\{}|<>" // Recursively remove all instances of "()", "[]", "{}", and "<>" from U.
                    // "}"              "(["          ">[{"        "((((]"
mZ{Zc -1&2|1}       // Replace each char Z with (Z.charCodeAt() - 1) & 2 | 1.
                    // "1"              "33"          "133"        "33331"
U=                  // Save the result in U.
f31 |UfD |Ug        // Match all instances of "31" and "13" (D = 13) and bitwise-OR the results with the first char.
                    // null|null|1      null|null|3   null|13|1    31|null|3
                    // 1                3             13           31
                    // Implicit: output result of last expression
```