# Is there an unmatched parenthesis in this String?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, balanced-string

## Introduction

Given a String containing an arithmetic expression, your task is to output a truthy or falsey value based on whether it contains unmatched parentheses.

---

### Input

Your program should take in a String containing an arithmetic expression. It may take input in any way except assuming it to be present in a pre-defined variable. Reading from file, input box, modal dialog box etc. is fine. Taking input as function argument is allowed as well!

---

### Output

Your program should output a truthy or falsey value based on whether the input String contains any unmatched parentheses. It may output in any way except except writing to a variable. Writing to file, screen, console, terminal etc. is allowed. Outputting with function `return` is allowed as well!

---

### Rules

- For the purpose of this challenge, a parentheses is defined as any one of `[`, `{`, `(`, `)`, `}`, `]`. A parentheses is said to be unmatched if it does not have any corresponding opening/closing parentheses. For example, `[1+3` *does* contain unmatched parentheses.
- Ordering of parentheses does not matter in this challenge. So, `]1+3[` does not contain any unmatched parentheses. `{[)(}]` doesn't, as well.
- The input String will only contain following characters : `{`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `]`, `}`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `0`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `^`.
- Your program should output a truthy value if the input String contains an unmatched parentheses.
- Your program should output a falsey value if the input String does not contain an unmatched parentheses.
- You must specify the truthy and falsey values in your post.
- The input String will never be empty.
- If the input String does not contain any parentheses, your program should output falsey value.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

---

### Test Cases

```
Input            ->            Output

"{"                            Truthy
"{{{{}}"                       Truthy
"{[]}"                         Falsey
"[]]["                         Falsey
")()()()("                     Falsey
"1+4"                          Falsey
"{)"                           Truthy
"([)]"                         Falsey
"(()"                          Truthy
"2*{10+4^3+(10+3)"             Truthy
"-6+[18-{4*(9-6)}/3]"          Falsey
"-6+[18-{4*)9-6](/3}"          Falsey
```

---

### Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

---

### Note

I'll be adding a similar challenge but in which *order will matter*, after some time! Stay Tuned!

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is a dupe but I can't find the older one.

Comment: @StephenS [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118078/42545) is the one that came to my mind, but I don't think it's quite a dupe...

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77138/34388)

Comment: Can I use inconsistent values, given that they are always appropriately truthy or falsey?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, you can!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I've received a different answer to that question in the past. Maybe we should clarify on [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/what-outputs-should-i-allow-for-decision-problems) for a consensus?

Comment: @StephenS I don't think that this one is a dupe but the order will matter one is almost definitely a dupe of the one ETHproductions linked to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the brackets fully matched?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched)

Comment: @StephenS I think the fact that this is entirely orderless makes it quite different. Neither `][` or `([)]` would be valid in the other challenge but are valid here.

Comment: This question's title should *really* make it clearer that order is irrelevant. That's not what most people think about when talking about unmatched parentheses.

Comment: Is `(()` truthy or falsey? The rules and test cases don't make it clear whether the count of parentheses is important. All answers seem to assume that the count matters though.

Comment: @Arjun The rules say that a paren is unmatched if "it doesn't have a corresponding opening/closing parentheses" in the string. In `(()`, each paren arguably has a corresponding pair; the `)` is just used as a pair of two different `(`s. This interpretation of the task is not refuted by any test case, since the only case that has multiple parens of the same type happens to have a matching count.

Comment: @Zgarb Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. `(()` should return truthy as it contains an unmatched paren. Thanks for pointing that out. I will add that to the test cases. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 10 bytes

```
žuS¢2ô€ËP_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7S4EOLjA5vedS05nB3QPz//7pm2tGGFrrVJlqalrpmsRr6xrUA)

-4 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

`1` for truthy, `0` for falsey.

Its main power point is the `žu` builtin.

Explanation:

```
žuS¢2ô€ËP_
žu         Push '()<>[]{}'
  S        Split into individual chars
   ¢       Count occurrences of each char in the input. For <>, the count will always be 0
    2      Push 2
     ô     Split the array into pieces of that length, corresponding to respective matching brackets
      €    Map next command over the chunks
       Ë   Check if all elements are equal. If equal, it means that the corresponding bracket type is matched. <> will always be matched, since they will never occur in the input, so they'll both always have 0 occurrences
        P  Take the product of the boolean values. <> won't affect this, since it would always be 1
         _ Logically negate, convert 1 to 0 and non-1 (always 0 in this case) to 1
```

Comment: Who doesn't have a command that pushes `()<>[]{}`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing CJam doesn't, but you can get it with ``[{(<>)}]` ``.

Comment: @Challenger5 You just correctly ordered the brackets so that the `(<>)` won't affect the stack since it's in a code block, and then the codeblock goes into the list? Well, this challenge doesn't have `<>`, so you could just use `[{()}]\`` or `{[()]}\`` or even `{([])}\``. Oh wait a sec, you can actually use `{()}a\``.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yeah, I forgot about that.

Comment: @Arjun They're not handled, since they'll never be in the input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda s:map(s.count,'([{')!=map(s.count,')]}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjexQKNYLzm/NK9ER10julpdU9EWRUwztlZd839BUWZeiUKahjpQAReCEw2SRPCjY2OjkfmaGhCILGaobYJihCYyz0ir2tBA2yTOWFsDSBujyOmaaUcbWuhWm2hpWOqaadbqG8dil9YESsdq6BuD3A0A) Test cases from musicman523.

Checks if list of counts for each type of open paren matches that for the corresponding close parens.

The program is one byte longer

```python
q=input().count
print map(q,'([{')!=map(q,')]}')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to WheatWizard!

```python
lambda s:any(s.count(i)^s.count(j)for i,j in['{}','[]','()'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5hC4IwEIa/9yv2bXdOM51IBf2SdYIV0qSmqH2Q4W9fg4gmxMHd@9wDx/XzdO9M7prT2T3q5@VWs/FYmxnG7bV7mQk0Vt/YYtMNTMct00Zxu/CYK/INkBO6ftBmYg1wy3HzA0VLyIpIhYzwqXCXiWJ1AkPKI5vtRFFJAX7KlUtKobJ9YosIDkmJSyrpv0avCVLpX3Nv)

Comment: This can be made slightly shorter by ditching `r`.  [Try it online](https://tio.run/##bY5BCoMwEEX3PUV2mTG1GiPSFnqSdATbIg20UdQuJHj2NNCFEcrAH948@Ew/T8/OFr69XP2red8eDRvPjZ1hPNy7j53A6JywXkkStt3ADDNWc7fwPdcUApAT@n4wdmItcMdxt4KmJWZNpGNG@E18k6LcVGBMReJkLspaCQhbbVxaCS2PqSsTOKUVLpmi/xqDJshUeM1/AQ)

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to match the two characters into separate variables, removing the indexing and therefore saving 4 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ċÐ€“[]{}()”s2E€ẠṆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I9@EJj5rWPGqYEx1bXauh@ahhbrGRK1Dk4a4FD3e2/f//X0nXTDva0EK32kRL01LXLFZD37hWCQA)

`1` is truthy, `0` is falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>62</s> 61 bytes

Surprisingly pythonic for codegolf.

```
lambda x:all(x.count(y)-x.count(z)for y,z in("[]","()","{}"))
```

*-1 byte thanks to @musicman523*

Comment: You can use [musicman's trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124409/56656) to make this shorter. [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY5hC4IwEIa/9yvGvnjnNNMNqaBfsiZYIQk1RQycw9@@BhFNiIO797kHjuvNeO904ZrT2T3q5@VWk@lYawPT9tq99AgGq2@csekGYpKZtBqoVDShgL7ZhSK6fmj1SBqIbISbH0i1hCyVkiEjfCrc5UysTmBIRWzzHRMVZ@AnX7m0ZDLfp1bEcEhLXDKu/mv0WkHG/WvuDQ)

Comment: And now we have the same answers :) Although your post came before my edit, I did come up with it independently

Comment: Yeah, I'll leave it as is.

Comment: You could change `==` to `-` and keep `all`, then we have the same byte count but different answers

Comment: @musicman523 Alright then!

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
!'[](){}'=sHeda
```

This outputs `1` if unmatched, `0` if matched.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F9RPTpWQ7O6Vt222CM1JfG/S8h/9Wp1LvXq6NhaIBUdGxsNpDQ1IBDINNQ2AUlrAgmNaM1YIGWkVW1ooG0SZ6ytAaSNQTK6ZtrRhha61SZaGpa6Zpq1@saxKKKaQNFYDX1joBUA)

#### Explanation

```
!          % Implicitly input string. Tranpose into vertical vector of chars
'[](){}'   % Push this string
=          % Compare for equalty, with broadcast
s          % Sum of each column. This gives the count of each char of '[](){}'
He         % Reshape as a two-row column (in column-major order)
d          % Difference of the two entries of each column
a          % Any: gives true (1) if some entry is nonzero, false (0) otherwise
           % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 71 bytes:

```
x=>['()','[]','{}'].some(a=>x.split(a[0]).length!=x.split(a[1]).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58+1 = 59 bytes

+1 byte for the `-n` flag.

```ruby
f=->c{$_.count c}
p %w"() [] {}".any?{|s|f[s[0]]!=f[s[1]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYjBCoJAEEDv8xWrFey4rLqtSB2sDxmmKMGjhSYh4377ZnSJd3iPN0z3OW6SYZWyfewae2ple83bx9S/VBvgqXbvVKMiVhLS/NbPZ1nGpaORSuak@YZjDjEKCHEAYiZA/QOcqUAQNCHDPhNXmurijV7tEWxtyB2sVJk@2hpD4fnv4fpYFz58AA)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 57 bytes

```
x=>(g=z=>x.split(z).length,g`(`-g`)`|g`[`-g`]`|g`{`-g`}`)
```

Starting from asgallant's solution.

Matching returns 0. Non-matching returns non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

I can definitely golf this using subtraction instead but I'm running out of time. D:

```python
lambda s,c=str.count:(c(s,'(')!=c(s,')'))or(c(s,'{')!=c(s,'}'))or(c(s,'[')!=c(s,']'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5RC4IwEMff@xT2tDunmU6kAj/JWmCGFNSUbT2E7LOvlWAT4h7ufr//cdzwMtdeFq6rj@7ePM6XJtJJW2ujNm3/lOYALeiEAMF1/Z2QIPZqsuNsbWD5bIW3blA3aaIOPturH3BhQ@ZC8JARpgpdTsvFCQypiMd8S8sTo@A7W2RpRXm@S8cyhn1aoc2Y@B@jjwVkzL/m3g)

Comment: All instances of `!=` can be `-`.

Comment: This answer has already been out-golfed by a [far better answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124409/68615). Hence, I'd rather not try to golf this.

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 26 bytes

```
O`.
+`\(\)|\[]|{}

[^*-9^]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYixDQIxDAB774FkxwpPSPTiJ6BkAMdRKChoKBCd37OHSDTcFSfd@/F5vu7jgNc@bv0I3CtW2qvobg4gLcSt6RgGNnEHE3UQVQHCn5C4gBGcg6UTl5YZZzNBXFnSJVoJuMWVfMn692g@xSX7Fw)

#### Explanation

```
O`.
```

Sort all characters so that corresponding brackets are adjacent (since neither `\` nor `|` can appear in the input).

```
+`\(\)|\[]|{}
```

Repeatedly remove pairs of matching brackets.

```
[^*-9^]
```

Try to match any remaining brackets (the regex matches anything that isn't a `^` or in the ASCII range from `*` to `9` which, among the valid input characters, are only the 6 brackets). If we find any, that means that there was an unmatched one. The result will be a positive integer if the input was unbalanced, `0` otherwise.

Comment: `{{{{}}` is matched? Your code return `0` on that input.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, it should be fixed now (luckily at the same byte count).

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, <strike>95</strike> 86 bytes

```
param($s)$h=@{};[char[]]$s|%{$h["$_"]++};$h.'['-$h.']'-or$h.'('-$h.')'-or$h.'{'-$h.'}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwEETv@YoQYpOYptZGpEUK/Y@QihQhB4sSDz2s@fbUKD2UhX0zs3PYafz0fnb9MEQC5IgIGBsSjbUmUfB9ki5ltVVE2twIm3jJoTzL6qklX6m3m6qlKa8KqpzfVC1Coe1/LNbY8kIHsqAMEMYHDHHqfPfmdBbU3R8QGvNynV//oPOSAXWG0JZYKUND3YkZphIsU6NPgu9e/DzsPrCIccC0RSF@AQ)

Previous version

```
param($s)switch([char[]]$s){'('{$k++}')'{$k--}'['{$l++}']'{$l--}'{'{$m++}'}'{$m--}}$k-or$l-or$m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoMwDEXf/YoibrZ2xbmKbN9SuiEiOKYodeBDlm/vEvc0AvceTvKQZd76sA79OMYU0lOSgvPI7bx33Er@hrnS9X6iOKVTnvtSQHXW9d1qSW33nWm0q64G6kLeTKOwtP5fK9JelhbTT3KARIijgLi0oZ1ktqp1e767QbpuaAP9QQZymUP20hpzxWAM5o5gZOMZ2ADBxAYZyCBdzoGWFFMUAkX2SDB@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>149</s> 140 bytes

New solution incorporates bitwise operators (Thanks, arjun) and calculates if they are *not* equal, and uses or instead of and.

```
function f(x){return x.split("(").length!=x.split(")").length|x.split("{").length!=x.split("}").lengt|x.split("[").length!=x.split("]").length}
```

I don't yet have a snippet for this, so I'm not sure it works yet.

### OLD SOLUTION:

```
function f(x){return !(x.split("(").length==x.split(")").length&&x.split("{").length==x.split("}").length&&x.split("[").length==x.split("]").length)}
```

Checks if there are the same amount of one bracket and another, and then returns the opposite.

```js
function f(x){return !(x.split("(").length==x.split(")").length&&x.split("{").length==x.split("}").length&&x.split("[").length==x.split("]").length)}

/*"{"                            Truthy
"{[]}"                         Falsey
"[]]["                         Falsey
")()()()("                     Falsey
"1+4"                          Falsey
"{)"                           Truthy
"([)]"                         Falsey
"2*{10+4^3+(10+3)"             Truthy
"-6+[18-{4*(9-6)}/3]"          Falsey
"-6+[18-{4*)9-6](/3}"          Falsey*/

console.log(f("{"));
console.log(f("{[]}"));
console.log(f("[]]["));
console.log(f(")()()()("));
console.log(f("1+4"));
console.log(f("{)"));
console.log(f("([)]"));
console.log(f("2*{10+4^3+(10+3)"));
console.log(f("-6+[18-{4*(9-6)}/3]"));
console.log(f("-6+[18-{4*)9-6](/3}"));
```

Comment: I can save 3 bytes by making every == into a != And changing && to || but I'm on mobile

Comment: I think, bitwise operators instead of logical ones will do fine. Like `&` instead of `&&` and `|` instead of `||`.

Comment: You can remove the outermost paren after `return !`.

Comment: Do you even need a space after `return`?

Comment: I think you need that space otherwise JavaScript will count it as rerurnx and throw an error

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 87 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>s.Count(c=>c=='['|c=='{'|c=='(')==s.Count(c=>c==']'|c=='}'|c==')')
```

Pretty self explanatory, just test to see if the of left parenthesis equals the count of right parenthesis.

Comment: Please check on `{)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Basic.Net, <s>218</s> 192 Bytes

```
function t(m as string,v as string)
return Len(m)-Len(m.Replace(v,""))
end function
function b(q as String)
return not(t(q,"{")=t(q,"}")and t(q,"[")=t(q,"]")and t(q,"(")=t(q,")"))
end function
```

Comment: "around 218 bytes" I count 217. Also, `if (expr) then return false else return true` can be `return not (expr)`.

Comment: "around 218 bytes" I count 192. Do you have a trailing newline?

Comment: I dont know how to put line through 218

Comment: `<s>218</s>` works.

Comment: well I don't have trailing newline

Answer (score 0):

## PHP>7.1, 124 Bytes

```php
$t=!!$p=preg_replace("#[\d+/*^-]#","",$argn);for(;$p;$p=substr($p,1,-1))$t*=chr(($o=ord($p[0]))%5?$o+2:$o+1)==$p[-1];echo$t;
```

Instead of #`[\d+/*^-]` you can use `[^]{()}[]` or `[^\p{Pe}\p{Ps}]`

[IntlChar::charMirror](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.charmirror.php) `IntlChar::charMirror($p[0])==$p[-1]` instead of `chr(($o=ord($p[0]))%5?$o+2:$o+1)==$p[-1]` checks not if the char is an openining or closing punctation so we can not use it without additional check `&$p[0]<$p[-1]` +8 Bytes

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09a4ff10b2cb3093424f07d6579805575f99709e)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 151 bytes

A full Regex Solution

```php
for($c=$t=!!$p=($r=preg_replace)("#[^]{()}[]#","",$argn);$p&&$c;)$p=$r(["#^{(.*)}$#","#^\[(.*)]$#","#^\((.*)\)$#"],[$a="$1",$a,$a],$p,1,$c);echo$t&!$p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCsMgFET3vUW@n6CtKWRtpAcxWkRsXJTkI9mFHLtrq4XCbB7MG4YSlelBiS7o87JqMAcX52hvgwNVXlvmGDTuuuuQNMesKcflmSO9fYiCAzPONsNYBhJA/laEQup7DEpUCTM3wNzB71dxYmsxN5tG9k@80SwqWmnQa8CxLdVYiSRHiUGoGNKGe19/qFI@6zYEH1L8Ag)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 65 bytes

```
 #(let[f(frequencies %)](some not(map =(map f"[{(")(map f"]})"))))
```

So long keywords :/ Returns `nil` for falsy and `true` for truthy.